# How to benchmark Redis all operations at once

Tags: testing, redis, jmeter, performance-testing, benchmarking

When i try to benchmark redis using default benchmark all the operations are executing one after the other is there any way to execute all the operation parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I have used redis api in nodejs & express, and conducted the test using jmeter.

Here is my code,

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    
    var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(6379,"10.96.82.175");
    
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {    
              res.send("HEY  Nodejs runnning on 10.96.82.175:4000");
    });

    app.put('/set/:arg1/:arg2', function (req, res) {
    
          client.set( req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2,function (err, reply) {
            if (reply==null)
            {
              res.send("null");
            }
            else {
              res.send(reply.toString());
            }
    
          });
    });
    
    
    app.get('/get/:arg1', function (req, res) {
          client.get( req.params.arg1,function (err, reply) {
    
            if (reply==null)
            {
              res.send("null");
            }
            else {
              res.send(reply.toString());
            }
    
          });
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    
    app.get('/incr/:arg1', function (req, res) {
          client.incr(req.params.arg1, function (err, reply) {
            if (reply==null)
            {
              res.send("null");
            }
            else {
              res.send(reply.toString());
            }
    
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    app.put('/lpush/:arg1/:arg2', function (req, res) {
      client.lpush(req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2, function (err, reply) {
        if (reply==null)
        {
          res.send("null");
        }
        else {
          res.send(reply.toString());
        }
    
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    
    
    app.get('/lpop/:arg1', function (req, res) {
      client.lpop(req.params.arg1, function (err, reply) {
    
        if (reply==null)
        {
          res.send("null");
        }
        else {
          res.send(reply.toString());
        }
          });
    });
    
    
    
    app.put('/sadd/:arg1/:arg2', function (req, res) {
      client.sadd(req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2, function (err, reply) {
        if (reply==null)
        {
          res.send("null");
        }
        else {
          res.send(reply.toString());
        }
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    
    
    
    app.get('/spop/:arg1', function (req, res) {
      client.spop(req.params.arg1,1, function (err, reply) {
    
        if (reply==null)
        {
          res.send("null");
        }
        else {
          res.send(reply.toString());
        }
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    
    app.put('/zadd/:arg1/:arg2/:arg3', function (req, res) {
      client.zadd(req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2,req.params.arg3,function (err, reply) {
        if (reply==null)
        {
          res.send("null");
        }
        else {
          res.send(reply.toString());
        }
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    app.put('/hset/:arg1/:arg2/:arg3', function (req, res) {
          client.hset(req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2,req.params.arg3,function (err, reply) {
            if (reply==null)
            {
              res.send("null");
            }
            else {
              res.send(reply.toString());
            }
              //console.log(reply.toString());
          });
    });
    
    app.get('/hget/:arg1/:arg2', function (req, res) {
    
          client.hget(req.params.arg1,req.params.arg2,function (err, reply) {
    
            if (reply==null)
            {
              res.send("null");
            }
            else {
              res.send(reply.toString());
            }
              //console.log(reply);
          });
    });
    
    app.listen(4000, function () {
    
      console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
    });
```

and here is  my jmx file

[JMX FILE LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6lGbCWwC0HBV3V4enhkY0FBNWM)